# How to check if a order has a shipment in Magento?

Tags: magento

I need to check if an order has already some shipment set. The only data I can use is the increment id of the order. I'm getting an instance of a model order, but I don't see a way I can get a shipment instance.

I'm using this code:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
    ->loadByIncrementId($order_increment_id);
```

But how can I get a shipment instance? I know that I can call `Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->loadByIncrementId($shipment_increment_id)` but how do I get the shipment increment id?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assume that the person who wrote this might have also needed to do what you need to do. Generally,  when Magento objects have a one to many relationship you can find a method to load the many on the one.

You've got a class alias `sales/order`.

This corresponds to `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` (in a stock installation).

You can find this class at `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`.

If you examine this class, there are 7 methods with the word "ship" in them

```
function canShip
function setShippingAddress
function getShippingAddress
function getShip
function getShipmentsCollection
function hasShip
function prepareShip
```

Of those 7,  only the semantics of `getShipmentsCollection` indicate a method for grabbing an order's shipments. So try

```
foreach($order->getShipmentsCollection() as $shipment)
{
    var_dump(get_class($shipment));
    //var_dump($shipment->getData());
}
```

Or take a look at the source for `getShipmentsCollection`

```
public function getShipmentsCollection()
{
    if (empty($this->_shipments)) {
        if ($this->getId()) {
            $this->_shipments = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')
                ->setOrderFilter($this)
                ->load();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $this->_shipments;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alan! After taking a look at getShipmentsCollection() and Magento Collections, I figured out that using a getShipmentsCollection()->count()  is just what I need.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear as always ( I wonder why you don't work in Core Team :)
... However ...
it wouldn't be easier to check the order status = 'complete' ?
... So:  $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', $id)
->addAttributeToFilter('state', 'complete')

Answer (score 9):

Just to make it complete `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` has public method:
`hasShipments()`
which returns number of shipments and internally uses mentioned `getShipmentsCollection()`.